# Power fail while running defraggler SSD optimization

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, hardware-failure, power, defragment

Tonight I was running Defraggler's **Optimization** tool for SSD, but at some point power in my home went down, and the pc has been powered off in the middle of the job.
I ran it again, to find out my poor ssd seems to be almost full, but yesterday it had 400 free gbs. What happened? Is it broken? How could I repair this?

[Screenshot](https://i.ibb.co/SJqXDG7/IMG-20190727-212608.jpg)

Comment: The screenshot is of very poor quality. Is this the system disk? Windows 10? Advice: Backup your data first, then run `chkdsk`.

Comment: I uploaded a better version of the screenshot, sorry for that one. It was the C: drive on a windows 10 machine

Comment: Defragmenting an SSD gains nothing and only shortens it lifetime. My advice is still the same: Backup your personal data, then run `chkdsk` without parameters and add its output to your post.

Comment: To add to harrymc's comment, Defragging can be helpful with a HDD if files get extremely fragmented (don't do it unless there is serious fragmentation), because then it takes more time to retrieve files; the head needs to travel to each piece's location and wait for the sector to spin into place.  SSDs don't work that way.  Everything is stored in random locations (fragmented by design), and the retrieval time is the same no matter where the pieces are.  The SSD's controller decides where to store everything and continually moves things around for wear leveling.  (cont'd)

Comment: That's all hidden and invisible outside the SSD.  The controller synthesizes a fake indication of where things are so that the SSD looks to the system, and acts like, a hard drive.  Your defragging software is trying to move around phantom things, which does nothing but use up SSD write cycles (which are finite).  You should never try to defragment an SSD.  If yours is still working, you will need to identify what is taking up the additional space and clean it up.

Comment: Thank you all for you answers, but please read carefully my question before answering! I never ran a Defrag on my ssd, I know I shouldn't do it. I ran Defraggler's "Optimize" tool for SSDs. I don't know what it does, but it's not a Defrag. The program actually notices if you try to Defrag SSDs and prevents you from doing it.

Comment: Well that's very different.  :-)  Thanks for adding the clarification, it will save other readers who aren't familiar with Defraggler from jumping to the wrong conclusion.